# Add PropertyChangedCallback to a readonly dependency property of the base class

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, readonly, inotifypropertychanged

I need to register a property changed callback method to `IsHighlighted` property of a menuitem.
But on executing I get an exception that says that IsHighlighted is registered as readonly.

Any ideas to add the callback method, or is there another way to check the property changing?

```
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    static MyMenuItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyMenuItem),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyMenuItem)));
        
        /* IsHighlighted was registered as readonly and is not possible 
        override metadata without an authorization key. */
        IsHighlightedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyMenuItem),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsHighlightedChanged)));
    }

    private static void OnIsHighlightedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.onpropertychanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by using `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`.

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(IsHighlightedProperty, typeof(MyMenuItem))
    ?.AddValueChanged(this, (s, e) => OnHighlightChanged(IsHighlighted));
```